# Normal distribution, Components, Help with final step

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A worn poorly set up machine is observed to produce components whose length x follows a normal distribution with mean 20 cm and variance 2.56 cm. Calculate:

a) the probability that a component is is at least  24 cm long

b) the probability that the length of a coponent lies between 19 cm and 21 cm

a) $Z=\frac{24-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}=2.5$

This corresponds to a value of .9938 on the z table. Then do I take $1-.9938=.0062$?

b)

$\frac{19-20}{\sqrt{2.56}} \leq Z \leq \frac{21-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}$

$-.625 \leq Z \leq .625$-Is this work correct? Where do I go from here?

How is it that $\Phi(.625) -\Phi(-.625)=.46.....$

when $\Phi(.625)$ corresponds to an area of .73405?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can request a further clarification in the comments. I only saw your edit by chance.

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes, you are correct. We have that
$$
P(X>24)=P\biggl(\frac{X-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}>2.5\biggr)=1-\Phi(2.5)\approx0.00621,
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

b) You work is correct. You only need one final step
\begin{align*}
P(19<X<21)&=P\biggl(\frac{19-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}<\frac{X-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}<\frac{21-20}{\sqrt{2.56}}\biggr)\\
&=P(-0.625<Z<0.625)\\
&=\Phi(0.625)-\Phi(-0.625)\\
&\approx0.73401-0.26599\\
&=0.46802
\end{align*}
since
$$
P(x<\xi\le y)=P(\xi\le y)-P(\xi\le x)
$$
for any random varialbe $\xi$ and any $x<y$.